# Using EXTJS4, how to post multiselct combo content to PHP

Tags: php, json, extjs4

Using EXTJS4, I have a multiselect combo control inside of a form, that is creating an array of selected values in JavaScript. I need to send this form data (3 other text field values), as well as the output from the multiselect (an array - ["value1", "value2"], etc.) to a PHP script, to then load the values into a Oracle database. I will need the static values from the form, as well as one each of the array elements passed back to add the new record to the database. I am not sure how to convert the array passed in from the multiselect to something that PHP can understand.

For example if the form passes back - "fname": John, "lname":Smith, "email":jsmith@email.com, "fav_color": ["red", green", "blue"]. Do I need to create 3 queries to write the these values into the database - { "John, Smith, jsmith@email.com, red", "John, Smith, jsmith@email.com, green", "John, Smith, jsmith@email.com, blue" } or how do I "split" or explode the values coming in from JSON to allow PHP to read so I can write the query?

Answer (score 0):

Decode the JSON in PHP with `json_decode()`, and any arrays it contains will be PHP arrays.  E.g.:

```
$data = json_decode(

  '{ "fav_color" : [ "red", "green", "blue" ] }',

  TRUE

);

var_export( $data );

// Outputs:

array (
  'fav_color' =>
  array (
    0 => 'red',
    1 => 'green',
    2 => 'blue',
  ),
)
```

So that will get you access to the array in PHP -- not sure what queries you need to run to accomplish what you want with that data.

## Combinations

> how do then put each array element with each static element passed in?

There are different ways you could go about this. Here are a couple:

1)

```
$combinations = array();

foreach ( $data[ 'fav_color' ] as $color ) {

  $combination = $data;

  $combination[ 'fav_color' ] = $color;

  $combinations[] = $combination;

}
```

2)

I don't know how you're extracting the data from the form to serialize as JSON, but if your HTML looked like this...:

```
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="static[fname]" value="First" />

<input type="text" name="static[lname]" value="Last" />

<input type="text" name="static[email]" value="Email" />

<select multiple name="fav_color[]">

<option value="red" selected>Red</option>

<option value="green" selected>Green</option>

<option value="blue" selected>Blue</option>

</select>

</form>
```

...and you submitted the form to PHP, you'd have this data structure in `$_POST`:

```
array(

  'static' => array(

    'fname' => "First",

    'lname' => "Last",

    'email' => "Email"

  ),

  'fav_color' => array( 'red', 'green', 'blue' )

)
```

So then, similar to #1, you could do:

```
$combinations = array();

foreach ( $data[ 'fav_color' ] as $color ) {

  $combination = $data[ 'static' ];

  $combination[ 'fav_color' ] = $color;

  $combinations[] = $combination;

}
```

Comment: how do then put each array element with each static element passed in?

Comment: this is JSON passed to php: {"data":{"ID":"","FAMILYNAME":"2G","TABLENAME":["TABLE_A1","TABLE_A1B","TABLE_A2 "],"TARGETNAME":"","GROUPNAME_SN":"C_6610","FLAVORNAME_SN":"_F_SYMB","GROUPNAME":"","FLAVORNAME":"","TARGETLABEL":"6610 [Full Symbian]","TARGETVALUE":"","ITEMREL":"","ITEMREF":"","ITEMNAME":"","ITEMMNEMONIC":"","ALLOWED":"","FOOTNOTES":"","DETAILS":"","VOID":""}}